# Two dimensional arrays populating does not work javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

When i try to create two dimensional array in javascript using loop, it gives me following error:

> Cannot set property 'indexis' of undefined

Code:

```
var indexes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < headingsArray.length; i++) {
            if (headingsArray[i].toLowerCase().indexOf('name') != -1) {
                indexes[i]['indexis'] = i;
                indexes[i]['headingis'] = headingsArray[i]; //assuming headingsArray exist
                indexes[i]['valueis'] = rows[0][i]; //assuming rows exist
            }
}
```

Comment: Multidimensional arrays are a pain in javascript sometimes.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the inner arrays/objects as well, or else `index[i]` is undefined, so `index[i]['indexis']` will throw an exception.

```
var indexes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < headingsArray.length; i++) {
    indexes[i] = {}; //<---- need this
    if (headingsArray[i].toLowerCase().indexOf('name') != -1) {
        indexes[i]['indexis'] = i;
        indexes[i]['headingis'] = headingsArray[i]; 
        indexes[i]['valueis'] = rows[0][i];
    }
}
```

You described it as a multidimensional array, but you're using it as though it's an array of objects (because you're accessing named properties, instead of numbered properties). So my example code is creating objects on each iteration. If you meant to have an array of arrays, then do `indexes[i] = []`, and interact with things like `indexes[i][0]` rather than `indexes[i]['indexis']`

Answer (score 2):

You need an object before accessing a property of it.

```
indexes[i] = indexes[i] || {}
indexes[i]['indexis'] = i;
```

Comment: it looks more like an array of objects, because of the named properties.

Answer (score 0):

define **temp var** with field initialise to null & use **push()** function of JavaScript

```
for (var i = 0; i < headingsArray.length; i++) {
var temp={indexis: null,headingis:null,valueis:null};;
            if (headingsArray) {
                temp['indexis'] = i;
               temp['headingis'] = headingsArray[i]; //assuming headingsArray exist
                temp['valueis'] = rows[0][i];
                indexes.push(temp);
            }
}
```